# Crysis on Windows 8.1 triggers low-memory warning

Tags: memory, windows-8.1, gaming

A more specific case of "[How do I make the Windows low memory warning less sensitive?](https://superuser.com/questions/585560/how-do-i-make-the-windows-low-memory-warning-less-sensitive)". Please don't migrate this post to Arqade; I was directed to post this question here from Arqade.

---

I just got a new top-of-the-line Sager/Clevo laptop running Windows 8.1 Pro, and it passes the *Crysis* (2007) benchmark maxed out with flying colors. However, I'm getting low-memory warnings from Windows:

> ### Close programs to prevent information loss
>
> Your computer is low on memory. Save your files and close these programs:
>
> `Crysis.exe`

*Crysis* is definitely not using an inordinate amount of memory. According to the Task Manager, the system has 8 GB of RAM of which less than 3 GB are in use, with Crysis having allocated only 218 MB of memory. Obviously, this warning is not justified. Why is Windows giving this warning, and what can I do?

The specifications of the *Dragon* as follows:

> - **CPU:** Intel Core i7-4800MQ, 4 cores (8 threads), 2.7 GHz
> - **GPU:** NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780M, 4GB GDDR5
> - **Memory:** 8GB DDR3 1600 MHz (2x4GB)
> - **Storage:** 750 GB 7200 RPM hard drive
> - **OS:** Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit

Comment: Did you disable your pagefile?

Comment: Looks like this may be a problem with Windows 8.1. Check out this thread to see many people with the same problem, no solution tho.
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-gaming/your-computer-is-low-on-memory-when-its-clearly/6fd6d158-1835-4179-b09f-975ea65e4281

Comment: How much video memory is in use? Memory stats usually only refer to mainboard ram. I expect the gtx780M is a mobile card and they don't always have as much dedicated video ram as a desktop version (and then laptop manufacturers may have their own oem spec). I don't have win 8.x so I don't know if it complains about low memory conditions WRT gpu.

Comment: also: crysis 32 bit or 64 bit binary?

Comment: 32-bit executable. The GPU actually has 4 GB of VRAM onboard.

Comment: This reminds me of Ye Olde problem where the system address space gets eaten up such that the memory can't be properly referenced. (VCache)

Comment: @Bigbio2002: The pagefile has not been disabled.

Comment: how large of a page file do you have set up, is is very small?

Comment: It's automatically managed and should grow by itself if required.

Comment: Fixed yet DragonLord? Hope fully after windows update?
Related: http://superuser.com/questions/715757/11gb-standby-ram-file-low-memory-warning-battlefield-4-win-8-1?noredirect=1#comment917020_715757 --not 4 you Dragon, for others ha

Comment: @Pathfinder It's been resolved. Besides, the *Dragon* has been upgraded to 24 GB of memory.

Comment: @DragonLord Good to hear!

Comment: I know this is a little old, but it's plain impossible for Crysis to use as little as 218 MB of memory. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://www.overclock.net/t/1409290/windows-8-can-i-disable-the-memory-warning:

> 1. Click **Start**, click in the Start Search box, type `gpedit.msc`, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. MMC will start with the Local Group Policy Editor open.
> 2. In the navigation tree, expand **Computer Configuration**, expand **Administrative Templates**, expand **System**, expand **Troubleshooting and Diagnostics**, and click **Windows Resource Exhaustion Detection and Resolution**.
> 3. In the console pane, right-click **Configure Scenario Execution Level**, and then click **Properties**.
> 4. On the **Setting** tab, select **Disabled**, and then click **OK**.

Comment: Great, a Group Policy solution. Although this requires the Pro edition of Windows 8.1 (which I have), the check goes to you.

Comment: Text was copied from another site, so I've added a link, placed the content in a blockquote, and modified the formatting for clarity.

Comment: Hey DragonLord. I was in a hurry while writing this. This is a Windows 8.1 related issue. I highly recommend to set the **game resolution** to your **desktop resolution** this will fix the **Memoryleak**! Like you i wasn't able to see the memory consumption in the taskmngr but if you user [procexp](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) you will notice the issue.

Comment: This is exactly the same as: "Hi, I have a warning light on my car". (Technician reaches behind dashboard and cuts the cable to the warning light) "there, fixed". Shouldn't we be looking for an explanation for the warning and fixing the condition instead of turning it off?

Answer (score 2):

This is a freaking nightmare
I buy a new Dell laptop and a copy of Fifa 14. And windows 8.1 won't let me play - it keeps popping this abomination of a warning throwing me out of the game. The group policy answer works only on Win Pro which I don't have.

However [MoralPanik & the internet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/08ecb6b8-a5b6-445d-a71e-65eafa9692e4/disabling-the-close-programs-to-prevent-information-loss-dialog-in-vista?forum=itprovistasetup) is here to help..

Open up the registry in admin Mode. For all of the following registry folders, use Context menu > Permissions > Advanced to make yourself or administrators the owner (instead of TrustedInstaller). Ok out and give the same credentials Full Controls over the folder.
This will let you delete the registry folder.

Blow away the following three folders (ensure you have a restore point/exported registry dump if you're wary).

- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro
  l\WDI\DiagnosticModules{5EE64AFB-398D-4edb-AF71-3B830219ABF7}]
- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro
  l\WDI\DiagnosticModules{45DE1EA9-10BC-4f96-9B21-4B6B83DBF476}]
- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WDI\DiagnosticModules{C0F51D84-11B9-4e74-B083-99F11BA2DB0A}]

Follow this up with a reboot and you can know play your games in peace!

Answer (score 0):

right click on the game's executable file and go to: `properties > compatibility` check `run this program in compatibility mode` and change the drop down list to `Seven` or `Xp` and see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

so the issue is seem to be with the intel drivers;  i just moved from a AMD FX to I7 4770, and started getting this error. I was using the 4600 IGU  and AMD R9 290, tho i had the HDMI plugged into the IGU for most use. i deiced to  disable the IGU and just use the R9... 2 days later.. no more error.. before i was getting it every 5 h before..  teaches me for going intel....