# 11GB Standby RAM File.. Low memory warning Battlefield 4. WIN 8.1

Tags: memory, windows-8.1, pagefile

Hey I'm a computer enthusiast/programmer.

**Problem:** Low memory warning on a: when playing battlefield 4. It's to do with Virtual Memory.

Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The following programs consumed the most virtual memory:
bf4.exe (4720) consumed 1562423296 bytes, 1.5GB
chrome.exe (10652) consumed 143052800 bytes, 0.1GB

**Verdict:** only 20% of ram is active. the rest 80% is standby ram. Should windows not clear it? and NOT USE SSD PAGEFILE?

[image]

My understanding of standby ram is that it is norm that 11GB will load. The 11GB could be anything.. movie files, programs, autocad. When you need to use them, it's already in fast RAM not the pesky slow HDD.

Thing is, 11GB Standby ram should be totally deleted if say BF4 needs working space. Is windows trying to move it to the 2GB SDD Pagefile?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem is a shortage of virtual memory, not a shortage of physical memory. You may have plenty of money in your bank account, but that doesn't mean you can keep writing checks. How much of your page file is in use?

Comment: Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The following programs consumed the most virtual memory: bf4.exe (4720) consumed 1576943616 bytes, chrome.exe (10652) consumed 143052800 bytes, and KillerNetManager.exe (8864) consumed 122294272 bytes.

Comment: David, this was a error report in the event log. 1.5GB BF4, 0.1GB Chrome and Killer respectively

Comment: Yes, so you're barking up the wrong tree. The problem was low virtual memory, not low physical memory. So free/used RAM has nothing to do with anything. Something seems wrong -- with a pagefile whose size is system managed, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: lol, barking up a smaller tree. How should I optimise this? Really Windows should not use virtual mem -_- 16GB..

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Something, likely not a program (or your event log would have caught it), is consuming huge amounts of backed virtual memory. Perhaps it's a buggy driver?

Comment: Try disabling paging.

Comment: Disabling paging.. I really don't want to. Many complex programs such as Sony Vegas video editing (+32GB File Paging) are programmed with page file in mind. Stability issues will 99% likely emerge.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/698358/crysis-on-windows-8-1-triggers-low-memory-warning

Comment: gladiator2345: You can't disable paging. You can disable the pagefile but paging to and from disk still happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran windows update. Problem's gone now. At least for now.
EDIT: Haven't seen this problem emerge since Feb, It's May now, So problem's definitely fixed

Possible Causes: Faulty GPU Driver Memory leak when BF4 is in a different resolution from desktop native resolution.

+Plus+

Windows OS error which makes it dump the GPU working set RAM data in the SSD Pagefile.

For others who are still experiencing this problem, you can bypass this error by disabling windows pagefile. However do this only if you have more than 8GB of Ram, you risk bricking your computer.

Comment: can you provide more information about the "OS error dumping GPU working set"? I would attempt to google this but "windows OS retard" is going to give a lot of search noise. It seems like something people might benefit from knowing.

Comment: "GPU working set data" is what I call the map visual data (from BF4) which the GPU calls and renders when the game requires it to, this is not the data held in GPU DDR5 ram.

Answer (score 4):

Pathfinder, I have had a similar issue, but for whatever reason i need a certain amount of rep to even comment on your posts so I am forced to post, incorrectly, through this route.

you say you just ran windows update? I have tried windows update with no avail. the strange thing is, I can jump in the game, and sometimes it will try to crash the game claiming low memory, but I will be allowed to continue to play, on ultra, with 60-90fps no problem

also, please give me rep points so i can post in these forums correctly, it is beyond silly that I need 50 points to comment on other's solutions