# Windows 10 claims that memory is full, when it really should not be

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have a Windows 10 PC with 8GB of RAM that frequently generates "low memory" warnings, even when barely any applications are open. Example:

[image: All the windows memory tools in one screenshot]

Can anyone explain what is going on, and what can be done to fix this?

[This question indicates that the problem is the committed memory due to lack of swap](https://superuser.com/questions/1065853/windows-10-low-memory-warnings-when-i-have-plenty-of-available-memory), but how would you fix this?

Comment: Is the task manager memory graph open before the error comes up? If not this could be due to an application using all remaining memory and closing/crashing when memory peaks.

Comment: No, the error message was first. What I find confusing is that I don't see any memory metric that confirms the error message.

Comment: Keep task manager open, until you get the message. You can then see if memory did max out. Also have a look in the windows event viewer. It should give you more information about the error. I don't know exactly where it will be but check the Application and System Logs

Comment: Look at your commit charge: 30.8/31.9 GB. Something commit a lot of memory.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=windows+10+low+memory+warning