# Windows 10 out of commited memory, but not out of physical memory

Tags: windows-10, out-of-memory

I'm getting out of memory errors in my applications. But it appears that I'm not out of physical memory? I'm only hitting the committed memory limit.

[image: Text]

Comment: Did you perhaps disable the page file or limit its size? Don’t.

Comment: @DanielB O, I thought it was good to disable/limit swap to disk?

Comment: Disabling the swap file prevents data pages being paged out. So Windows will page out code pages to the exe, dll, or font file. You are not out of memory. You need to paste details about the program.

Comment: This isn’t about code vs. data. It’s about commit (reservation) vs. actual use.

Comment: I especially recommend reading [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1066362/219095) on the linked question. It explains why this is happening in greater detail.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks dude!