# Low memory warning Windows 10

Tags: memory, java, windows-10

I have 16 gigs of physical RAM, running on windows 10 professional.

I get a 'windows is running low on memory' notification here and there, only when playing minecraft through Curse Launcher with dedicated 5 gigs RAM maximum.

When the event occurs I check the performance tab in task manager; I've been keeping it up since this is a relatively persistent issue; and my rig never exceeds 75% physical RAM usage (~12 gigs).

This issue never occurred on my windows 8.1 setup prior to the upgrade last month.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You are running out of virtual memory.  More information is required about your configuration.  Since I assume your world has continued to expand since you performed the upgrade, the amount of virtual memory Minecraft requires continued to increase.  This has very little to do with with Windows 10.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Perhaps this setting got changed during the upgrade. Currently set to 1 gig across all drives.

Comment: You should have a 24-36GB page file based on the amount of system memory you have.

Comment: Ok I will adjust the page file size and see if the issue resolves. I suggest moving your comment (with elaboration of the size, and why) to an answer so I can credit your help :)

Comment: It also is possible you are running out of video memory.  Can you track your video memory usage and report the results?  As for me submitting an answer to this question.  [It already exists;](http://superuser.com/questions/585560/how-do-i-make-the-windows-low-memory-warning-less-sensitive?lq=1) It just wasn't written by me.

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/698358/crysis-on-windows-8-1-triggers-low-memory-warning?lq=1) question's answer explains how to suppress the message itself.