# Can we decrease page swapping?

Tags: windows, virtual-memory, paging

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Windows Swap (Page File): Enable or Disable?](https://superuser.com/questions/14795/windows-swap-page-file-enable-or-disable)
>   [Can we decrease page swapping?](https://superuser.com/questions/122736/can-we-decrease-page-swapping)

My system has a 5GB RAM.
And my paging file size is 2GB

Even though I have many RAM, page-swapping still occurs.
But I don't want to that.

I know how adjust the paging file size.
If I resize the paging file size(ex 200MB?), Doesn't Windows System do any swapping?

Are there side-effects?

Comment: ahhaaaa, sorry. It's my fault. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Benjamin: please read the FAQ

Comment: Duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/14795/windows-swap-page-file-enable-or-disable

Comment: this is an exact duplicate (user crosspost) of http://superuser.com/questions/122736/can-we-decrease-page-swapping

Answer (score 1):

My computer -> Properties -> Advanced tab -> "Settings" button in the Performance box -> Advanced tab -> "Change" button in the "Virtual memroy" box -> uncheck the "Automatically manage paging file size for all drives" or similar checkbox -> select the "No paging file" radio button.

I strongly encourage you to research what this does and understand the side-effects. There are some pretty hefty side-effects of doing this and I'm not going to get into those.

Comment: Thanks Jax. But it not my point. :)

Comment: You cannot control paging swapping from your application if there is excess available RAM. One situation where an application can reduce swapping (when the amount of RAM in use exceeds the available) is to ensure loops do not force memory access from different pages. But aside from this there's little you can do to prevent Windows from continually swapping.