# 64 bit processor and 16GB of memory, should I disable the paging file?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Swap (Page File): Enable or Disable?](https://superuser.com/questions/14795/windows-swap-page-file-enable-or-disable)

I have a pc with an Intel i7 2600k x64 processor, Windows 7 64bit and 16gb of RAM. Is it safe to disable the paging file? Will it improve the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend against it - I'd let windows decide how to handle the paging file. Whatever you're using will be in ram anyway, and will only be [swapped out when inactive](http://lifehacker.com/5426041/understanding-the-windows-pagefile-and-why-you-shouldnt-disable-it).Swapping out is good, since it means you don't have to have memory in use to store things that arn't immediatly needed. It will also reduce the space available for pre-fetching and cause all sorts of wierdness.

According to You will also not be able to write kernel dumps should there be a crash (see the last bit of [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx))

Leave it on automatic, and forget about it, unless you have a compelling reason to. If you *do* want to manually size it it should be at least as large as ram, for kernel dump purposes.

Comment: That'll be one huge kernel dump :)

Comment: Should I set it to 16gb then? Wouldn't that b a bit excessive?

Comment: The kernel dump is actually much much smaller than that. My kernel dumps have been about 1GB to 2.5GB.  My personal recommendation is 3GB for a page file.